# apply clicked on table header in pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

this is my caller file which helps me generate ui of table where i can write data.the problem here is i want to sort the data when i click on the header of the table according to that column. i can sort the data easily as i have a backend data(not present in this code as it will not be needed here) but i am unable to apply click function on headers of the table. i want to apply clicked.connect on different table header. thanks in advance :)

```
from table import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui # Import the PyQt4 module we'll need
import sys # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import os

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is my table.py which has ui code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'table.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Row", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "class", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "marks", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.connect(self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL("sectionClicked(int)"),self.fun)

def fun(self,i):
    print("index clicked is"+i)
```

Comment: Can you highlight how you solution solves the OP's problem? From the current state of your answer, it's very hard to determine what has been done to fix the problem.

Comment: this function i added as an answer helps me return the index of the header i click in the table.

Comment: u must refer to qtableview header connection in pyqt

Comment: Where did you get SIGNAL? It's not in the question. I tried `from signal import signal as SIGNAL`, but I'm just guessing and that doesn't work. How did your main class gain a `connect` method that you can call `self.connect()`?